# Is it ok to use pair tags instead of non-pair tags in in freemarker? As in <#else /> instead of just <#else>?

Tags: freemarker

The main reason for this for me is to be able to pretty print my freemarker code by html editors (like a plugin in notepad++). When I use just <#else>, the indentation is wrong. When I use <#else />, it's ok. It seemed to work so far, but I'm not sure if I'm not doing something horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<#... />` is supported for most core directives, including `#else`. (The ones where it's not supported are those that you aren't supposed to use without nested content anyway, like `#list` and `#if`.) However, allowing `<#else />` and `<#elseif ... />` is actually a legacy bug. They work the same as without `/`, and this bug won't be fixed in FreeMarker 2.x for backward compatibility, so there's nothing to worry about. But they are in principle incorrect as `#else` and `#elseif` has their nested content (own block) under them, so they are actually not closed right after the tag. Instead, they are implicitly closed by the next `<#else ...>`/`<#elseif ...>` or `</#if>`. So `<#else />` is tolerated but is not a nice style.

As of indentation in editors, the editor should know if which directives support nested content. Like if the directive name is "include", then it knows that no indentation is needed after that tag. `#assign`/`#local`/`#global` is somewhat tricky, as they have two forms: `<#assign x = ...>` and `<#assign x>...</#assign>`. Also, there's a problem that new directives are added sometimes, so the editor won't yet recognize them. Luckily that happens rarely, so it's not an impossible situation.